# Use Cocoa Touch Framework in iOS and WatchKit

Tags: ios, watchkit, ios9, watchos-2

I have a Cocoa Touch Framework that I developed for using in both my iOS app and my WatchKit app on iOS 8.  I have no problems with iOS 8, however when I move the project to iOS 9 and update the WatchKit app to run natively I get the following error:

```
ParkFinderKit was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'ParkFinderKit.framework' because it doesn't contain platform 'watchsimulator' in its SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS 'iphonesimulator, iphoneos'
```

I attempted to manually add watchossimulator and watchos to the list of supported platforms:
[image: Configured Supported Platforms]

However this produces another error:

```
ParkFinderKit was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'ParkFinderKit.framework' because its SDK is platform 'com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator' and it needs to match platform 'com.apple.platform.watchsimulator'
```

Any ideas as to how to solve my issue?

Comment: I have the same problem, and cannot fix it the way you did, did you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, it looks like you cannot use a Cocoa Touch Framework inside of a WatchKit app.  I was able to get around this by creating a new *Watch Framework* target and then assigning each file from the original framework to the new framework in the Target Membership options.

[image]

This accomplishes my goal of sharing code between iOS and WatchKit without having duplicate code.

Comment: This doesn't work in Xcode 7 beta4 - its the same problem but the other way round,  watch kit frameworks don't support iPhone platforms .  does any one have another answer ?

Comment: @ChrisBaxter have you try to Clean before Build?

Comment: @g0ld2k, have there been an update to the solution for xcode 9+?

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral nope, I ended up dropping the WatchKit app from my app